# Temp table trouble in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I've used temporary tables before without any trouble, but today, they are not working for me. This returns

> . #MyTemp not found

from the last line.

```
scBld.CommandText = "select top 10 * into #MyTemp from elig_feeds";
scBld.ExecuteNonQuery();
scBld.CommandText = "select count(*) from  #MyTemp";
int p = (int) scBld.ExecuteScalar();
```

If I remove the "#"s, it works fine.

The only thing that has changed recently is version compatibility of the database, but I don't see that would be a factor. The db is 2005 developer edition.

Thx.

Comment: A temporary table is only visible to the session(spid) which created it. If the connection changes, the spid will change and you won't be able to access it. After the query finishes, the session is dropped and so is the temp table. A global temp table, on the other hand, is visible to all sessions, so one session can create it and another can access it.

Comment: That's all true, brian, but the four lines above were executed in order as shown using the same SqlCommand and the same open SqlConnection. There is another open SqlConnection. When I changed the order of operation, I got these test statements to execute, but the desired program code with more complicated SQL still did not execute.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue today with 2005 Express both using ODBC and OLE DB.
As explained in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130779.aspx) this behavior might be due to using prepared statements, which are wrapped into temporal stored procedures when prepared.

> In SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2000, and SQL Server 7.0, the prepared
>   statements cannot be used to create temporary objects and cannot
>   reference system stored procedures that create temporary objects, such
>   as temporary tables. These procedures must be executed directly.

Supplying statements directly using SQLExecDirect did help to fix the application. Not sure how that should be applied to ADO.NET though.

Answer (score 1):

Check if connection is getting closed automatically.  You are executing two different commands, depending on connection settings, it may get reset after you call ExecuteNonQuery().

[Temp tables are destroyed when connection is closed.]

Comment: Search for connection release mode.  You are probably releasing connections aggressively.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with connection pooling, but I don't see how to control it. I was able to put all relevant statements in one CommandText, and get it to work that way.